# Slim 3 Middleware Redirect

Tags: php, authentication, slim, slim-3

I want to check if a user is logged in. Therefor I have an Class witch returns true or false. Now I want a middleware which checks if the user is logged in.

```
$app->get('/login', '\Controller\AccountController:loginGet')->add(Auth::class)->setName('login');
$app->post('/login', '\Controller\AccountController:loginPost')->add(Auth::class);
```

Auth Class

```
class Auth {
    protected $ci;
    private $account;

    //Constructor
    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $ci) {
        $this->ci = $ci;
        $this->account = new \Account($this->ci);
    }

    public function __invoke($request, \Slim\Http\Response $response, $next) {
        if($this->account->login_check()) {
            $response = $next($request, $response);
            return $response;
        } else {
            //Redirect to Homepage
        }

    }
}
```

So when the user is logged in the page will render correctly. But when the user is not autoriesed I want to redirect to the homepage. But how?!

```
$response->withRedirect($router->pathFor('home');
```

This doesn't work!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to `return` the response. Don't forget that the `request` and `response` objects are immutable.

```
return $response = $response->withRedirect(...);
```

I have a similar auth middleware and this is how I do it which also adds a 403 (unauthorized) header.

```
$uri = $request->getUri()->withPath($this->router->pathFor('home'));
return $response = $response->withRedirect($uri, 403);
```

Comment: In OP's case, they didn't define a `$router` variable before using it. Where do you define `$this->router` assuming your Middleware didn't inherit from another class?

Answer (score 3):

Building off of tflight's answer, you will need to do the following to make everything work as intended. I tried to submit this as a revision, given that the code provided in tflight's answer would not work on the framework out of the box, but it was declined, so providing it in a separate answer:

You will need the following addition to your middleware:

```
protected $router;

public function __construct($router)
{
    $this->router = $router;
}
```

Additionally, when declaring the middleware, you would need to add the following the constructor:

```
$app->getContainer()->get('router')
```

Something similar to:

```
$app->add(new YourMiddleware($app->getContainer()->get('router')));
```

Without these changes, the solution will not work and you will get an error that $this->router does not exist.

With those changes in place you can then utilize the code provided by tflight

```
$uri = $request->getUri()->withPath($this->router->pathFor('home'));
return $response = $response->withRedirect($uri, 403);
```

Answer (score 0):

make basic `Middleware` and inject `$container` into it so all your middleware can extends it.

```
Class Middleware
{
  protected $container;

  public function __construct($container)
  {
    $this->container = $container;
  }

  public function __get($property)
  {
    if (isset($this->container->{$property})) {
      return $this->container->{$property};
    }
    // error
  }
}
```

make sure your `Auth` middleware on the same folder with basic middleware or you can use namespacing.

```
class Auth extends Middleware
{
  public function __invoke($request, $response, $next)
  {
    if (!$this->account->login_check()) {
      return $response->withRedirect($this->router->pathFor('home'));
    }

    return $next($request, $response);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
http_response_code(303);
header('Location: ' . $url);
exit;
```

Comment: Please try to explain your answer instead of just posting code.

Comment: @NahuelIanni, it is self-explanatory if you know PHP.

Comment: While I'm sure this probably works, OP was probably looking for a solution that used the functionality of the Slim Framework, instead of plain PHP.

Comment: @KimberlyW I could not find anything built-in that worked from within middleware.

Comment: Yes this is a solution, but not a proper one.

Comment: @aod, what is the proper one?

Comment: @systemovich you can see above.

Comment: While maybe not pretty, it's easy to read and avoids the craziness of having to bubble up through the middleware keeping track of whether or not the redirect is a response. The complexity of redirects inside middleware, with Slim, comes from the fact that you shouldn't run the inner layer of the middleware, or the redirect won't work.