# Redirect with HTTP 403

Tags: php, slim, http-status-code-403, http-redirect, slim-3

I'm using Slim PHP and want to redirect the user to `/login` if they are not logged in but try to access a page that requires a user to be logged in. When searching for how to build my middleware, I find variations of this code all over the place

```
class Auth{    
    public function requireLogin(Request $request, Response $response, $next){
        if( !isLoggedIn() ) return $response->withRedirect('/login', 403);

        return $next($request, $response);
    }    
}
```

for example in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36523161/930640) and [this Slim discourse answer](https://discourse.slimframework.com/t/logged-in-pages-vs-non-logged-in-pages/961/2).

The problem is that I can't get the combination of redirecting and HTTP 403 to work. From what I can tell, normal HTTP redirects are restricted to the [HTTP codes 3xx](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections). Indeed, the above code works fine when used with for example `302`.

Am I missing something, or are all the answers that combine `withRedirect` and `403` "incorrect" (as in not causing an actual redirect of the users browser)?

Comment: 403 is specifically **Forbidden** it's not a redirect header at all... I think you'd be better off doing one or the other personally; e.g. you *could* **302** to a *login failed* page.

Comment: This is the kind of things you would see in an API, the API would returns 403 (more of a 401 actually ) and then the frontend would catch this error, handling it by redirecting you to the login page. In your case, since it's the PHP redirecting it, you could throw an exception and catch it in an error handler but you wouldn't see the 403  error. You kind of don't need it in your case.

Comment: As a clarification between 403 and 401. The 403 error code means the authentication was a success but the user lacks the permission required to perform an action. The 401 simply means an authentication is required to access this page, or this action. In your case, i think the 401 error would be more appropriate.

Comment: This other question seems relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839585/what-is-correct-http-status-code-when-redirecting-to-a-login-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your application is an HTML website that's accessed using a web browser, then the browser will only redirect if the status code is a `3xx` one.

If your application is an API that's accessed using an HTTP client then you have more leeway. For an API, you'd use a `403` or `401` status code to indicate that the request cannot be fulfilled without authorisation. You may also include a `Location` header to tell the client where to go to get authorisation, but of course it's up to the client if they follow up on that link.